# liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: ORA-00911: invalid character [Failed SQL: drop table $Y_USER_NAME}

Tags: database, liquibase

I am try to run sql script through liquibase, I set a property MY_USER_NAME like this

```
${MY_USER_NAME}
```

, but when I try to use it in my sql file when I run the liquibase for some reason the opening bracket is being remove so instead of evaluating my property it ends up $Y_USER_NAME}

I have my master changelog file master.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <databaseChangeLog
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

  <include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="changelogs.xml"/>
```

And my changelogs.xml is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
    xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.4.xsd">

<property name="MY_USER_NAME" value="LALA"/>
<include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="TEST.sql"/>


</databaseChangeLog>
```

TEST.sql

```
drop table ${MY_USER_NAME};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my issue, in order for properties to be evaluated in sql file sql should be wrapped not included.

so instead

```
<include relativeToChangelogFile="true" file="TEST.sql"/>
```

This should be used

```
<changeSet author="xxx" id="my changeSet" >
<sqlFile  relativeToChangelogFile="true" encoding="utf8" path="TEST.sql"/>
</changeSet>
```